# Center UILabel content in a view with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

When you have a label with its contents centered, is it better to set the label's alignment to NSTextAlignmentCenter or center the whole label within the parent view?

Here's how I want the label to sit within its parent view:

```
|  |                            |  |  
|  |       [ Label Text ]       |  |
|  |                            |  |
```

Where the outermost `|` is the view and inner `|` is the contentView.

I'm creating the content view and label:

```
    _contentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    _contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    _contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    _titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    _titleLabel.text = @"Hello world";
    _titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    _titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    _titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
    _titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

The view's layout is controlled by auto layout:

```
- (void)setupConstraints {
    NSMutableArray *constraints = [NSMutableArray array];

    UIView *contentView = self.contentView;
    NSDictionary *viewsDict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(contentView);
    NSArray *cn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[contentView]-|"
                                                          options:0
                                                          metrics:nil
                                                            views:viewsDict];
    [constraints addObjectsFromArray:cn];

    cn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-40-[contentView]"
                                                 options:0
                                                 metrics:nil
                                                   views:viewsDict];
    [constraints addObjectsFromArray:cn];

    UILabel *titleLabel = self.titleLabel;
    NSDictionary *viewsDict1 = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(titleLabel);
    cn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[titleLabel]-|"
                                                 options:0
                                                 metrics:nil
                                                   views:viewsDict1];
    [constraints addObjectsFromArray:cn];

    viewsDict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(titleLabel);
    cn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[titleLabel]-|"
                                                 options:0
                                                 metrics:nil
                                                   views:viewsDict];
    [constraints addObjectsFromArray:cn];

    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
}
```

I would like the label to be centered rather than left aligned, which is what got produced with this code.

[image: result]

The orange is the label, yellow is the content view.

Comment: Can't reproduce, please show more code.

Comment: You need to set constraints for contentView as well as your label. Also, the view and label should have translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints set to NO.

Comment: rdelmar - thanks. It was that contentView didn't have the correct constraints.